# Trying to generate 9 digit numbers with each unique digits in Java

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I am trying to generate **all** permutations of 9 digit numbers with each digit from **1 to 9** used exactly once with no repeats.
for example, 123456789, 132456789, 987654321 etc....
The reason i tagged this question with recursion is because I believe thats how I have to solve this question but I'm not sure how to do that in Java

The program should return a list of int arrays.

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
int[] values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int count=0;
int count2=0;
int count3=1;

while(count2<9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2) {
    for(int i =1;i<values.length-1;i++) {
        if (count<8*7*6*5*4*3*2) {
            Integer toMove = values[i];
            values[i]=values[i+1];
            values[i+1]=toMove;
            count++;
        } else if (count>=8*7*6*5*4*3*2&&count3<9) {
            values[0]=1;
            values[1]=2;
            values[2]=3;
            values[3]=4;
            values[4]=5;
            values[5]=6;
            values[6]=7;
            values[7]=8;
            values[8]=9;
            Integer toMove = values[0];
            values[0]=values[count3];
            values[count3]=toMove;
            count=1;
            count3++;
            i=0;
        }

        count2++;
        list.add(values);
    }
```

Comment: You have tagged this question with recursion, but your example is not a recursive algorithm. Is it supposed to be? And are you sure about how many iterations you want (9!)?

Comment: Do you want to generate permutations? Wikipedia describes some algorithms to do that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order

Comment: Are you trying to get all permutations, or just a handful of 9 digit numbers with each of 0-9 appearing once?  If it's the latter, just create an array of the digits and shuffle it.

Comment: I am trying to generate all permutations of 9 digit numbers with each digit from 1 to 9 used exactly once with no repeats. for example, 123456789, 132456789, 987654321 etc.... The reason i tagged this question with recursion is because I believe thats how I have to solve this question but I'm not sure how to do that in Java
Sorry for the confusion....

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you were looking for

```
//Initialize List
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

//Shuffle List      
Collections.shuffle(numbers);

//Obtain Array
Integer randomizedArray[] = numbers.toArray(new Integer[0]);

//Print Array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomizedArray));
```

Comment: I am trying to find all permutations, not just one, so this method wont work and if I just randomised this array numerous times I would get some arrays which are the same and I don't want that

Comment: The logic of shuffle and array creation can be rolled into a method and called repeatedly.
The randomness of numbers can be obtained via 
 shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd)

Comment: But its possible for the random method to cal the same array more than once, and I need every permutation